# Database Open but Oracle gives ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, oracle-rac

We are using 4 node Oracle 10GR2 RAC in Windows x64. 3 instances of our database crashed today and later started normally. I started them by connecting (Remote Desktop) to individual instances and executing startup command in sqlplus.

I can connect to database using SYS account but when I try to connect using application user account, I get following error:

> An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
>
> ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
>   01033. 00000 -  "ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to log on while Oracle is being started up
>              or shutdown.
>   *Action:   Wait a few minutes. Then retry the operation. Vendor code 1033

Interesting thing is my instances started and database are open according to following queries.

```
SELECT * FROM GV$INSTANCE;

SELECT * FROM GV$DATABASE;
```

I tried to use following command thinking that there is a mistake.

```
SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01531: a database already open by the instance
```

I also tried to control RAC node statuses using following command.

```
srvctl status database -d DBNAME
```

database status command is following:

```
Instance DBNAME1 is running on node NODE01
Instance DBNAME2 is running on node NODE02
Instance DBNAME3 is running on node NODE03
Instance DBNAME4 is running on node NODE04
```

So I can connect to database using SYS account, but WHY not application user account?

Situation resolved itself in 15 minutes. I can connect to database now. But there is nothing in the alert logs about this situation. Should I check additional places to learn about real problem? Is there anything I can do in similar situation?

After a while, I understood why this is happening! Oracle executes following command which we can see in alert logs.

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN
```

Some time later , We can see following line in alert.log

```
Completed ALTER DATABASE OPEN
```

Only after this line, we can connecto to database. Interesting thing is in this 4 node RAC , we need to wait for this event in all instances before database start serving.

Comment: No mention off rollback/recovery in any of the alert logs?

Comment: Check the alert logs. 
Pretty sure there was as crash recovery process working.